# Jenkins Git plugin cannot obtain ~/.ssh/config file

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-kubernetes

I'm using [helm Jenkins chart](https://charts.jenkins.io/)

Pod template for agent

```
        jenkins:
          clouds:
            - kubernetes:
                name: "kubernetes"
                serverUrl: "https://kubernetes.default"
                skipTlsVerify: true
                namespace: "jenkins"
                jenkinsUrl: "http://jenkins:8080"
                jenkinsTunnel: "jenkins-agent:50000"
                containerCapStr: 42
                maxRequestsPerHostStr: 64
                retentionTimeout: 5
                connectTimeout: 10
                readTimeout: 20

                templates:
                  - name: "test"
                    label: "jenkins-agent"
                    # Enable whether the POD Yaml is displayed in each build log or not, `true` by default.
                    showRawYaml: true
                    volumes:
                      - hostPathVolume:
                          mountPath: "/var/run/docker.sock"
                          hostPath: "/var/run/docker.sock"

                    containers:
                      - name: "backend"
                        image: "mycustomimage"
                        privileged: true
                        alwaysPullImage: true
                        command: "/bin/sh -c"
                        args: "cat"
                        workingDir: "/home/jenkins/agent"
                        ttyEnabled: true
                        resourceRequestCpu: "500m"
                        resourceRequestMemory: "1Gi"
                        resourceLimitCpu: "2000m"
                        resourceLimitMemory: "2Gi"
                    imagePullSecrets:
                      - name: "registrysecret"
```

in the end of my dockerfile for **"mycustomimage"**

base image is **debian:buster**

```
RUN useradd -u $JENKINS_USER_UID $JENKINS_USER -m -d $JENKINS_HOME -G docker
USER $JENKINS_USER
RUN mkdir $JENKINS_HOME/.ssh && ssh-keyscan ssh.github.com > $JENKINS_HOME/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN echo "Host github.com\n    Hostname ssh.github.com\n   Port 443\n   User git" > $JENKINS_HOME/.ssh/config
```

Issue is really tricky.

1. If I'm using pipeline from SCM Jenkins can easily obtain JenkinsFile from the repo(that checkout is going through jenkins-master pod for sure)
   Than inside JenkinsFile I have next

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        node { label 'jenkins-agent'}
    }
 ....
stage('Source Code Checkout') {
            steps {
                container('backend') {
                    git branch: 'main',
                        credentialsId: 'git_user_ssh',
                        url: 'git@github.com:org/repo.git'
```

Jenkins always returns

```
[2022-08-27T22:03:06.716Z] stderr: ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
[2022-08-27T22:03:06.716Z] fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
[2022-08-27T22:03:06.716Z] 
[2022-08-27T22:03:06.716Z] Please make sure you have the correct access rights
[2022-08-27T22:03:06.716Z] and the repository exists.
```

Checking user in container

[image]
Exec into pod and try same [image]

as you can see ssh command obtains config and it is trying to clone repo using 443 port(not 22 as jenkins). Then I put private key in .ssh folder and clone works perfectly.
That means there isn't network issue.

2. Trying to clone in "Pipeline script" with git command in sh

```
        stage('Source Code Checkout') {
            steps {
                container('backend') {
                    script{
                       sh "git clone git@github.com:org/repo.git"
```

result [image]

3. Trying to clone via GitSCM plugin in "Pipeline script"

```
        stage('Source Code Checkout') {
            steps {
                container('backend') {
                    git branch: 'main',
                        credentialsId: 'git_user_ssh',
                        url: 'git@github.com:org/repo.git'
```

result
[image]

jfyi
[image]

Could someone please explain to me the cause of problem?
Or how to specify port while cloning repo through Jenkins.
Thanks in advance.

Jenkins home as was requested

```
                container('backend') {
                    script{
                        sh "cd $JENKINS_HOME || true"
                        sh """cd ~
                            pwd
                            ls -la
                        """
```

[image]

Comment: Is `$JENKINS_HOME` == `~/` ? JENKINS_HOME is the root of the Jenkins install, not the Jenkins user home directory.

Comment: @IanW Hello, thanks for the answer. Adjusted post with this information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I detected that next warning appears sometime

```
warning: JENKINS-30600: special launcher org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pipeline.ContainerExecDecorator$1@49c426f3; decorates RemoteLauncher[hudson.remoting.Channel@456b185:JNLP4-connect connection from 172.26.80.22/172.26.80.22:57964] will be ignored (a typical symptom is the Git executable not being run inside a designated container
```

So I decided to **rebuild base jenkins/inbound-agent** image
with the following

```
FROM jenkins/inbound-agent:4.13-2-jdk11
ARG JENKINS_HOME=/home/jenkins
ENV JENKINS_HOME=$JENKINS_HOME
USER jenkins
RUN mkdir $JENKINS_HOME/.ssh && ssh-keyscan ssh.github.com > $JENKINS_HOME/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN echo "Host github.com\n    Hostname ssh.github.com\n   Port 443\n   User git" > $JENKINS_HOME/.ssh/config
```

and.. git checkout is working for now.
I don't understand how **jnlp** container influences on checkout inside another container based on my **"mycustomimage"** image.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a non-standard port, specify it in the URL

```
  git clone --help
  ...
  ssh://[user@]host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it is not working. 
stderr: ssh: Could not resolve hostname : Name or service not known